# How to fix autogenerated index in dataframe by real index after getting data from pd.read_html

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am not able to find how to index my dataframe columns properly

I tried some methods but not able to find right one

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('sbi.html')
data = df[1]
```

[image: Screenshot]

i want the second row as my index of columns in which "Narration" is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `header` parameter to `1`:

```
data = pd.read_html('sbi.html', header=1)[0]
```

Or use `skiprows` parameter:

```
data = pd.read_html('sbi.html', skiprows=1)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem


```data = pd.read_html('sbi.html', header=0)[1]```